# Two wordpress site's user database will be update automatically

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have to wordpress web site and these two site have two deference database. this two web site in under same domain.

```
one is "Main Domain" and other is "Sub-domain".
like: [1]www.domain.com and [2] www.subdomain.domain.com
```

Now I want, If anybody register at [www.domain.com] - same time a user will create at [www.subdomain.domain.com] 's user database.

*How can I do this? Is this possible? If possible- plz anybody help me.

I m waiting for this reply.and advance thanks

Comment: your wordpress installtion is multisite enabled?

Comment: no, how to enable wordpress multisite

Comment: it should be done when installing wordpress not now.

Answer (score 1):

there  are two way to do that. the first is. the create a one database and used it in both site.

if you used the one database in both site then the set sub domain site url in wp-config file. then when the sub domain site is running the url is replace by main domain.

and second way is to create two database connection and manually insert user in second site database.

when the wordpress create new user this hook is fire.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);

}
```

using this hooks you can create new user to your second site with different database connection.

Using This function you create multiple connection in wordpress.

```
$newdb = new wpdb( 'USERNAME' , 'PASSWORD' , 'DATABASE NAME' , 'HOST' );
```

Comment: Thanks @renishkhunt
I need second way. But I can't able to do this. where will be database connection. how to do database connection for this hook.

N.B: My two site has two database. So I think, here need new database connection for this hook.

Comment: @CoderSaifulIslam you just create second database connection in config file so you get easy to any file. and in this hook you fire php query to second database. using this function you can create new connection for database. $newdb = new wpdb( 'USERNAME' , 'PASSWORD' , 'DATABASE NAME' , 'HOST' );